# Alternative tool like hping3 tool for windows

Tags: windows, networking, ping, hping

Can we use `hping3` in Windows 64-bit OS?
If not, can anyone help with some other tool with CLI commands use to ping?

Answer (score 1):

PsPing from microsoft sysinternals might do what you want

`.\psping.exe -n 10 <host>:<port>`

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-at/sysinternals/downloads/psping